# Precise measurement of time interval in CocoaTouch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, time, intervals

I have a class which must have a property of some kind of timestamp, representing the moment of time when the instance of this class was created. And then when having multiple objects of this class I need to find the time interval between the creation of these objects.
And the usual interval is going to be up to 10 seconds, so I need precision of at least 1 second, but something like 0.1-0.001 second would be much better.

What is the best option to use for this property?

As far as I know, NSDate has precision up to 1 second.
I believe that I need something related to CFTimeInterval. I've used it for view animation with CADisplayLink. It provided the CFTimeInterval value for each moment of screen update and I could calculate the time interval between two CFTimeInterval's very easily. 
But how do I assign the value to this CFTimeInterval at any moment of time?

Comment: NSDate is more precise than 1 second. Put two `NSLog(@"%f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);` next to each other and watch the output.

Comment: Wow, it's really precise. Thank you. That suits my needs. Maybe post it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDate will work, as Matthias Bauch's comment indicates. You can also just use CFTimeIntervals though:

```
CFTimeInterval currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

Do note that this function and NSDate are both based on an absolute reference date (Jan 1, 2000 in this case). This means that if the system's clock is changed while your app is running, values obtained before the clock change won't correctly compare to values obtained afterward.